# Use a Gravity forms form as new post form for different categories

Tags: wordpress, forms, categories, gravity

I have two gravity forms that allow my user to submit events and files to website's pages, but i want their posts be displayed as new posts of a specifics categories.

I have found this link below and yet try it and it returm me php script error: https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_after_submission/

Let's someone who have yet do it and successed tell me in simple words step by step, what to do: files i have to modifie, what i have to write....

thanks

Answer (score 0):

This plugin will allow you to generate posts from Gravity Forms into a specific post type and/or category.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-custom-post-types/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i have already installed this plugin but it don't give me in the advanced tab the option "save as post type". I got only the option "save to taxonomy", but nothing is available in taxonomy dropdown list. Have you faced already this issue?

Comment: The "Save As Post Type" option is only available on the Post Title field on the "Advanced" field settings tab. Are you not seeing it there?